# cocoapods integration on existing workspace

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I'm new to `CocoaPods` and was able to use it on some sample project.

Now I'm trying to integrate it into my current working project.

The project is a `iOS` application project which use target dependency on other some static library I've created which also uses another static library with dependency I created.

So basically it's 3 project nested in each other.

After `init`&`install` the `Podfile` on the main project I can't build the project
getting the error: `Library not found for -IPods-MYAPPNAME`.

Any ideas what should I do to integrate an existing project with many frameworks and dependencies to `CocoaPods` or is it a lost battle?

Comment: Simular case works fine for me, show your `Podfile` and `.podspecs` for libraries you created

Comment: hmm.. i dont have pod files for the libraries i created.

Comment: Sorry, your app project's `Podfile` and `.podspecs` for the libraries